# Importing and Exporting data/tables from excel to sql 2008r2

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, datagridview

I want to Import excel Tables(randomly) into Sql server 2008r2 on button click event. Save it to database and run query.
Later after I get the output(after running the query), I want to show it in datagridview (Windows Application) and then save it in Excel file.
Using VS 2010, SQL server 2008 r2. While running it is showing an error regarding `ConfigurationManager` does not exits in context.
This whole Programming is to be done using c#.

```
private void btnok1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (lblexcel1.Text=="")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have not Select Excel File. Please Select Respective Excel File");
            }

        //Create connection string to Excel work book
        string excelConnectionString =@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Details.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;""";

        //Create Connection to Excel work book
        OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);

        //Create OleDbCommand to fetch data from Excel
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select [ID],[Name],[Location] from [Detail$]",excelConnection);

        excelConnection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader dReader;
        dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection);sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Details";
        //sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("ID", "ID");
        //sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
        sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);


    }
```

`

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);